# How to set value in dropdown using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am setting a value in a drop down using jquery in the following ways.

```
$("#dropDownItems option[value='--Select--']").attr('selected', 'true');

 $("#dropDownItems option[value='--Select--']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But none of these are working for FireFox! and is working fine for remaining browsers.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem with CSS implementations with single quotes. Have you tried `$("#dropDownItems option[value=\"--Select__\"]").attr("selected", "selected");`?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Try Prop instead of attr.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.

```
$('#dropdownID').val("Value to be selected");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#dropDownItems").val("--Select--");
```

Or, if you just want to select the first option regardless of its value, you can define this helper function:

```
$.fn.selectFirst = function () {
    return $(this).find("option:first").attr("selected", "selected").end();
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$("#dropDownItems").selectFirst();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the default value and it is the first element, you can do:

```
$('#dropDown')[0].selectedIndex=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are multiple ways to do it. The easiest way:

```
$("#dropdownID").val("dropdownValue");
```

This will work just fine, but it won't fire the change event if you have in any case. To resolve it, use it like below:

```
$("#dropdownID").val("dropdownValue").change();
```

Other possible ways:

```
$("#dropdownID").attr('selected','selected');

$("#dropdownID").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('[id*=_dropdown]').val("--Select--");
```